# How to upgrade from 16.10 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, 16.10

I am unable to upgrade to 18.04 with the following error message

[image: An upgrade from 'yakkety' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool.]

> Can not upgrade
>
> An upgrade from 'yakkety' to 'bionic' is not supported with this 
>   tool.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS releases direct to 18.04 LTS (ie. LTS to next LTS).  Ubuntu 16.10 release-upgraded to 17.04 then 17.10 (both now EOL) and then to 18.04 LTS.  If you want to release-upgrade less often, use a LTS next time.  The only supported way is via install; I would use 'something-else' & use existing partitions without format. It'll take note of your added packages, wipe system directories then install, add-back your additional programs (if from Ubuntu repos) without touching user data.  It's what I'd do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

1. backup the entire disk using Clonezilla just in case
2. backup /etc/apt/sources.list
3. edit it as prompted here: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)
4. that page also states to:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   but I did:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
5. I restored sources.list and replaced yaketty with bionic
6. I tried to update with the GUI tool but at this point something was failing due to the fact that my /etc/fstab didn´t include for some unknown reason an entry for mounting /. I corrected it and rebooted
7. After that the upgrade tool ran smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will release-ugprade direct to 18.04 LTS (ie. LTS to next LTS).

Ubuntu 16.10 release-upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, then to Ubuntu 17.10 (*both now EOL*) and then to 18.04 LTS. ie. the only tested and supported non-LTS upgrade-path is via every release (not skipping releases).  If you want to release-upgrade less often, use a LTS or long-term-support release next time.

The only supported way is via install; I would use '*something-else*' & use existing partitions without format. It'll take note of your added packages, wipe system directories then install, add-back your additional programs (if from Ubuntu repos) without touching user data. It's what I'd do.

*Please note backup any data before you do the re-install.  Better safe than sorry*

Comment: be careful to ensure the 'format' check-box is not ticked; otherwise you'll lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please backup all the files you have before trying to upgrade.

**Step 1:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

**Step 2:**

Change "Prompt" value typing:

```
sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Edit "Prompt= ", fill with "lts", so Prompt=lts. To ensure that we will upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu LTS. And for now the latest LTS version is 18.04.

[image: screenshot of terminal, showing the release-upgrades file open in a text editor]

**Step 3:**

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If any messages say *no New release not found*, type this command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Please wait for the installation to complete. If there is a Y/N dialogue, please read carefully.